# make VIEW of SHOW TABLE query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to make a VIEW of this SHOW TABLE query?

```
SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `db_name` WHERE `Table_type` = "Base table"
```

When I save this as a view (using phpMyAdmin) I get

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `db_name` WHERE `Table_type` = "Base table"' at line 4

when phpMyAdmin tries to execute this

> CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `Tables` AS SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `db_name` WHERE `Table_type` = "Base table"

Comment: are you want to show table status or structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` instead, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND table_name = 'mytable'
```

You can create VIEW on top of this query as well.

Comment: Thank you. This query works for me

    SELECT `TABLE_NAME`
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema = 'db_name'

but when I create as a view called 'LookupTables' I get 

#1109 - Unknown table 'LookupTables' in information_schema - Chris

Comment: Ah, phpMyAdmin switched to schema view so I had to switch back to my database, run a query on any table, click CREATE VIEW and save the view LookupTables that now works. Thank you